# How to display multiple (arbitrary) number of labels (tags) in single UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My aim is to display list of tags, sorted alphabetically in `UITableViewCell`. 1st cell - all tags starting on "A", 2nd - starting on "B" and so on. Have a look at the picture:

[image: Evernote app on iPhone Tag list]

So I d like to get same result. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it, not at all. I did some search but nothing similar. The number of tags in each cell is dynamic, so it gets difficult of me.

EDIT:
After thinking for a while, I came up with idea of creating labels in for loop and adding them to subview. Something like this:

```
NSInteger space = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50+space,10,45,67)];
    label.text = @"text"; //etc...
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    space = space+50;
}
```

Sourse:[iOS create UILabels dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634612/ios-create-uilabels-dynamically)
Need to work out how to group them in 2 columns and stuff.
Any fort her suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I think this could have been a good question. You should *remove* the *"point me to a tutorial..."* part and get back to programming/development. Asking for the tutorial or library will ensure its closed.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your suggestion. I did not know about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating label (tags) position gives you pain but nothing else. Lets say you calculated location.x if there are more than two tags this time you need to calculate location.y of third one. Even if you calculate both this time you need to calculate row height for per letter.

Tried to pull this one how you asked / described. To get good result too much work involves. Here how it looks what I did for testing.

[image]

Best way to accomplish this using UICollectionView in UITableViewCells or directly UICollectionView.

[image]

It is almost full project this is why it is hard to type it down here. You can find [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/) useful.

Comment: Thank you man. This is quite useful and gives me a way to work further.